# How to add line break in vim script

Tags: vim

I am a beginner in vim.

The following code is just a piece of code that i have. How to add line break between "just" and "an".

> call append(line('.') - 1,  'This' .'is' .'just' . "\r" .  'an' .
>   selected_content . 'example')

This code is not working. and got junk like (^M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your string into a |List|, and then, it'll work.

```
call append('.', ['This' .'is' .'just',  'an' . selected_content . 'example'])
```

If as I suspect the string is built, then is won't be difficult to use a list instead of a string in your code. Otherwise, you'll need to use `split(line, "\n")`